# Поиск и замена во всех php файлах рекурсивно

Tags: bash

Подскажите как найти кусок кода, в моем случае такой:

```
<div class="site-info">

</div><!-- .site-info -->
```

в любых php файлах во всех вложенных подпапках текущей папки и заменить его другим куском кода.
Уровень вложенности папок не ограничен, то есть во всех php файлах всех папок и подпапок текущей папки.

Comment: я [изложил ваш вопрос в **общем** случае](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573730/178576), который может быть полезен не только лично вам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

увы, с помощью возможностей программы *bash* это весьма трудноосуществимо.

но можно воспользоваться другими программами из состава операционной системы. например, весьма помогут программы *find* (для поиска) и *sed* (для изменения содержимого файла).

> в любых php файлах во всех вложенных подпапках текущей папки

```
$ find -type f -name \*.php
```

> заменить его другим куском кода

как я понял, приведены начальная и конечная строки, и всё между этими строками (включая сами эти строки) надо заменить на какой-то текст:

```
$ sed -i '/начальная строка/,/конечная строка/c\какой-то текст' файл
```

---

остаётся только «состыковать» эти две программы вместе, чтобы вторая получила список файлов от первой. для этого можно воспользоваться, например, программой *xargs*:

```
$ find опции.и.параметры | xargs sed опции.и.параметры
```

или, для вашего конкретного случая:

```
$ find -type f -name \*.php | xargs sed -i '/<div class="site-info">/,/<\/div><!-- .site-info -->/c\какой-то текст'
```

---

дополнительное чтение:

```
$ man find
$ man sed
$ man xargs
```

Comment: @alexader Нет нет, это не начальная и конечная строки , это и есть кусок который нужно заменить,

Comment: между этими двумя строками мне нужно вставить код, но там есть файлы где между ними уже вставлен код , следовательно вариант с начальной и конечной строкой не подойдет

Comment: т.е., три **конкретные** строки? тогда программу для sed придётся несколько усложнить. на будущее рекомендую чётче формулировать вопрос и убрать всё не относящееся к делу. типа «как найти файлы» или требование использования программы-оболочки для осуществления действий, для которых она абсолютно не предназначена.

Comment: *Стойте не меняйте* — да я и не собирался ничего менять. требующееся вам усложнение программы, ввиду бесполезности для кого-либо помимо вас, логично будет оставить вам в качестве домашнего задания.

Comment: Почему усложнение, разве не наоборот? заменить фрагмент "а" фрагментом "Б"

Comment: потому что у вас речь не о фрагментах строки, а о строках.

Comment: А вы написали "<\/div>" это не ошибка ? "\" перед "/"здесь специально?

Comment: `/выражение1/,/выражение2/` — это диапазон строк. если `выражение` содержит символы `/`, то их надо «экранировать».

Comment: Если  текст КОТОРЫМ нужно заменять содержит множество разнообразных символов: слэши , точки с запятой , кавычки и тд. Что можно сделать в такой ситуации?

Comment: в данном случае — практически ничего: команда `c\ ` «выдаст» всё подряд. разве что с одинарной кавычкой «посложнее». но лишь из-за того, что она в данном случае используется как ограничитель параметра, передаваемого программе *sed*. пример: `программа 'пара'\''метр'`, программе будет передана строка `пара'метр`