# замена нескольких строк

Tags: sed

как с помощью программы *sed* заменить несколько подряд идущих строк с определённым содержимым на что-нибудь другое?

---

пример:

```
строка
строка1
строка2
строка3
строка4
строка5
```

требуется заменить три строки — `строка1`, `строка2`, `строка3`, на `заменяющий текст`, чтобы получилось:

```
строка
заменяющий текст
строка4
строка5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

общая схема такова:

1. сначала надо найти первую строку из указанного списка и выполнить с ней некий блок команд:

   ```
   /строка1/{блок команд}
   ```
2. блок команд должен начинаться с помещения в *pattern space* необходимого количества строк из входного потока. делается это командой `N`. в данном случае надо получить ещё две строки, значит, нужны две команды:

   ```
   N;N;
   ```
3. после их выполнения в *pattern space* будет содержаться такой (в данном случае) текст (каждая команда `N` добавляет в *pattern space* символ новой строки `\n`, а затем очередную строку из входного потока):

   ```
   строка1\nстрока2\nстрока3
   ```
4. вот именно такой текст и надо будет использовать в качестве первого параметра команде `s` (`substitute`). а вторым параметром будет тот текст, который должен послужить заменой (`s/первый параметр/второй параметр/`):

   ```
   s/строка1\nстрока2\nстрока3/заменяющий текст/
   ```

   к слову: если внутри параметров присутствует символ `/` (который мы выбрали в качестве разделителей параметров команды `s`), то надо:

   - либо «экранировать» каждый такой символ с помощью обратного слэша (`\/`)
   - либо использовать в качестве разделителя другой, заведомо не встречающийся внутри параметров, символ. например, запятую: `s,первый параметр,второй параметр,`

---

итоговая команда будет выглядеть так:

```
sed '/строка1/{N;N;s/строка1\nстрока2\nстрока3/заменяющий текст/}'
```

---

пример для случая, когда заменять надо четыре строки — `строка1`, `строка2`, `строка3`, `строка4`:

```
sed '/строка1/{N;N;N;s/строка1\nстрока2\nстрока3\nстрока4/заменяющий текст/}'
```

как видно, добавилась одна команда `N` и немного удлинился первый параметр команды `s`.

---

### экранирование

если в тексте заменяемых строк встречаются мета-символы: `^`, `$`, `.`, `[`, то их потребуется «экранировать», добавив перед ними обратный слэш: `\^`, `\$`, `\.`, `\[`

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос старый, но я на него уже не в первый раз попадаю - первым в поисковике выпадает.

По предложению автора топика:

```bash
sed '/начало текста/,/конец текста/d'
```

эта команда удаляет все строки, расположенные от "начало текста" до "конец текста" включительно. Аккуратно: если "конец текста" не найден, удалены будут все строки от "начало текста" и до конца файла.

Ещё пример:

```bash
sed -i '/<script/,/<\/script>/s//<!--здесь был скрипт-->/g'
```

Comment: `\AначалоA,\BконецBкоманда` - так это ж, вроде как, самая банальная адресация. должно быть эквивалентно более распространённомму `/начало/,/конец/команда`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, да, действительно. Сейчас заменю ответ на более адекватный формат